# How to restrict the first char of a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am working with javaScript, I would like to restrict the first char of a string. I have the following regex to avoid especial characters in the whole string.

```
/[^0-9_a-zA-Z\s]/g
var text = 'foo#'
var transformed = text.replace(/[^0-9_a-zA-Z%$#\s]/g, '');// 'foo'
```

but additionally to that I don't want any number just at the beginning of the string but yes in other position of the string, what would be the regex for that?

```
var text = '1fo4565o'
var transformed = text.replace([?], '');// 'fo4565o'
```

Comment: Duplicate of so, so many questions.

Comment: "Any number", well, that'd be `\d` right? Even your own concoction `[0-9]` would work.

Comment: But `[^0-9_a-zA-Z%$#\s]` applied to `foo#` results in `foo#`.

Comment: Yes you are right that was my mistake. the correct example would be var text = 'foo#'
var transformed = text.replace(/[^0-9_a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');// 'foo'

Comment: `^\d+|` in addition to the beginning of the regex should

Comment: Thank you, you save me I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful sites for doing this kind of work are https://regex101.com/ or http://www.regexr.com/ as they show you the effects on target text, tell you exactly what each part is doing, as well as providing a cheat-sheet.

If you want to replace only the first character, anchor it to the beginning with the ^ character. \d+ is any digit character repeated at least once. | is match this group or the next group.
So combined we get:

```
   /^\d+|[^0-9_a-zA-Z%$#\s]/g
```

Which is match any digits repeated at least once at the beginning of the string or any character that isn't in this set.